# How to unlock a locked enterprise architect diagram?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I got an Enterprise Architect document which has its diagrams locked, see screenshot below from clicking in the diagram background using the context menu:

[image]

The Lock Diagram option is active and cannot be selected. (How) can I unlock the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the Enterprise Architect project was opened directly from an email.

Due to this, and the file probably got (file based) locked by Outlook, Enterprise Architect locked the diagrams.

Solution: save the file in Outlook (or whatever mail application) to another file location and open the Enterprise Architect from there.

A better solution would be that Enterprise Architect would show a decent warning message that the file is opened in some kind of readonly state.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that user security is activated. See https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/modeling/lockdiagram.html and references therein for further information.

Comment: I guess to ask the author to resend it without the protection then.

Answer (score 2):

The dirty way to disable security is by running a SQL

```
DELETE FROM t_secpolicies
```

This will clear the entry where `Property` = "UserSecurity". Now it's a plain model. Either you can run a script from within EA (if that was not blocked) using `repository.Execute("<the SQL>")` or doing so from an outside client (EAP is M$Access, others could be opened using Toad or similar clients).

The *legal* way is to enter a security key in the Enable Security (no typo, this is EA!) menu to disable it.

Comment: Probably the 'owner'  can remove the security (otherwise it's good to know about this).

Comment: You get the security license with your first purchase. I have no idea how this is checked against your other license. I seem to remember that it's independent of it but that's not a sure remembering. Thinking again, if you HAVE a sec-license it will work on any model regardless where you get it from since the model has no idea of who its creator (or his license) is.